# Hosting a Spring mvc + Hibernate + MySQL + Maven app in "Digital Ocean" cloud

Tags: spring-mvc, digital-ocean, broadleaf-commerce

I have raised a question in Digitial oceans's support forum, as to, How can I setup the Broadleaf ecomm based e-comm app in their cloud. but sadly, they have no reply to it.

Can someone tell me in details, as to what kind of "Droplet" i should opt for and what are the detailed steps to be followed for getting my app up and running in their cloud.

I have made the account, veriftied the payment and basic setup is up.

A detailed tutorial will be highly appreciated.

- Sumit

Answer (score 1):

A DigitalOcean Droplet is just a virtual server.  It is like any other server in the sense that it will come pre-installed with an operating system of your choice and you can then do whatever you like with that server.  How you use a Droplet, how many you use and what size you use depends on the software you plan to run and the expected workload.

You should first create a deployment design for your application based on the expected user load, hardware requirements of the software, architectural best practices, such as, whether you want to keep the application and database servers separate, whether you want redundancy and failover, etc. and your project's budget.  This will decide how many servers you will need, what their specifications should be, what operating systems you should use and which software component will be installed on which server.  You will need to do this exercise for every environment you wish to host, such as, development, integration, test, staging, production, disaster recovery, etc. and whether you wish to use Digital Ocean for each of these environments or only some of them.

Once you know the number and type of servers you need, pick up a Droplet that is the closest match for your requirements.  After you have launched a Droplet, it is just a normal server and you will use it like you would use any server running an operating system remotely.  You can install any software you like in any way you like.  In most cases you should be able to use one of the native Unix package managers like `yum` or `apt` to install common software such as Java, MySQL and Maven.  For custom software like Broadleaf Commerce, just follow their installation and configuration instructions.